# Sphinx: Autodoc ImportError

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I'm trying to auto generate the documentation for my Django project. The doctree gets generated on the html page but there is no documentation for any of the members within any of my modules. I keep running into this problem:

```
Running Sphinx v1.1.3
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/admin.py", line 1, in <module>
from tool.models import All_alerts
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named django.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
from django import forms
ImportError: No module named django
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named django.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/page1urls.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: No module named django.conf.urls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/page2urls.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: No module named django.conf.urls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/page3urls.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: No module named django.conf.urls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/page4urls.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: No module named django.conf.urls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/tests.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.test import TestCase
ImportError: No module named django.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: No module named django.conf.urls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/views.py", line 1, in <module>
from tool.models import Product
File "/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named django.db

/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:7: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.admin', it reported error: "No module named django.db", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:15: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.forms', it reported error: "No module named django", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:23: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.models', it reported error: "No module named django.db", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:31: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.page1urls', it reported error: "No module named django.conf.urls", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:39: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.page2urls', it reported error: "No module named django.conf.urls", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:47: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.page3urls', it reported error: "No module named django.conf.urls", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:55: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.page4urls', it reported error: "No module named django.conf.urls", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:63: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.tests', it reported error: "No module named django.test", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:71: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.urls', it reported error: "No module named django.conf.urls", please check your spelling and sys.path
/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/docs/tool.rst:79: WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'tool.views', it reported error: "No module named django.db", please check your spelling and sys.path
```

I've been scouring the web for any solutions. I tried rearranging the import statements within the modules but nothing is working.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/tim/Desktop/fqdn/mysite/tool/'))
```

All my modules are in the tool folder. Any help is desperately needed. Thanks!

Also, doesn't automodule encapsulate autofunction? So why would we ever use autofunction?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) to simplify the dependencies.

In your `conf.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import sys

MODULES = ['django']
for mod_name in MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = MagicMock()
```